# Mountain Lion: Not joining preferred WPA2 Wifi network

Tags: macos, network, wifi

My Mac Mini (2011) has always auto-joined networks fine until a few days ago when it stopped  auto-joining my preferred WPA2 wifi network when I start it up. When I click `Join Other Network` and then  `Show networks` my wifi appears. When I double click it I have to enter my password than my mac joins it. But the next time I start my Mac, I have to do that again.

How can I get auto-join to start working again?

Comment: Not mentioned, so I think I should ask. Have you checked if your preferred network is listed in "System Preferences - Network - WiFi - Advanced - Preferred Network"? If yes, delete it and check the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, now I can answer my question myself.

Go to **Keychain Access** and remove all airport passwords for this network from Login and System keychains.

Then create a new password in System. Enter the network password. Item Name and account name: name of the network. Click add. Then double click the new item in the list. Change kind to 'airport password'. Then click **Access Control** and select **Allow all applications to access this item.**

Restart your computer. If it doesn't join automatically join it manually, next startup it will work fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Preferences / Network / Wifi / Advanced** and remove your network from list of *Preferred Networks*.

Now go to **Keychain Access** and remove all airport passwords for this network from **Login** and **System** keychains.

Then restart your computer, join the network, select *save password* and *remember network*.

After that, it should join automatically.